# Revert to a specific MS Office version using PowerShell on a "start with 1-click" install

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office, reinstall, microsoft-office-2013, version

I used sometimes ago a PowerShell command that makes an installed version of MS Office to revert to an older version, any of those referenced at [Update history for Office 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2013)

But I don't remember the command, can you help?

The procedure was to launch PowerShell as an admin.
Then execute a command starting from somewhere into `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\` and ending with `=[the version you want to go to]` (like =15.0.4823.1004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't remember the command, can you help?

It's `%programfiles%\Microsoft Office 15\ClientX64\OfficeC2RClient.exe /update user updatetoversion=15.0.4823.1004`, this will only work with Click-to-Run installations of Office.

[Uninstall Office 365 Click-To-Run Updates](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/784)